# wrong double representation in sqlite data reader

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am using `SQLite` as my `database` in a `.NET 4.5` project. There is a table that holds a column of type `double`. The database access is wrapped into a class that lays inside a class library project/assembly.

The table is created as follows:

```
create table mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, myvalue DOUBLE, updateTime INTEGER )
```

I can insert new rows properly. When I inspect the database with `SQLite Browser`, I can clearly see the values are correctly inserted.

Now there is a command line project utilizing the database wrapper class. When I run this program all double values are correctly fetched.

In another project, being a `WPF` application, I'm using the very same database access wrapper library. But in this case, the `double` values are totally messed up.

When I put in **14.28** it reads out **-5.1897674825990524E-306**.
I guess there is just some problem of double representation here, but I do not know how to solve it.

**Summary:** `Command Line` works, `WPF` doesn't.

**EDIT**:
I have just seen, that every time I read the values out, the bogus value is changing. So there is some other mystical base.

```
 var query = "select id, myvalue, updateTime from mytable";
 var command = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
 var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read())
 {
    var myValue = (Double)reader["myvalue"];
    result.Add( myValue );
 }
```

UPDATE: it works well with int and string. but still no double.

Comment: Have you tried using other values besides double to check to see if they work?

Comment: Also, some code to see what is wrong might be an idea.

Comment: Have you debugged it ? in that case you must know ,where does the problem come

Comment: of course i debugged it. the values come straight from the debugger. but i cannot debug the sqlite sources.

Comment: @Hayden i tried it with REAL, won't work. float is not available.